# DynamoDB to S3 Extract Lambda Function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm writing a Lambda function in python to pull data from my DynamoDB Table, populate it in to a CSV file and then upload to my S3 Bucket.

I'm fairly knew to Python, I'm wanting to know if this is a step in the right direction or can it be corrected.

I'm also wanting the name of the CSV file to be the data and time of when the Lambda Function is invocated

```
import csv
import io
import json
import os
import boto3

from datetime import datetime

class DynamoDBExtractLambda(LambdaApplication):
    """Extract DynamoDB Lambda"""

    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        # Define DynamoDB table name and S3 bucket name using environment variables
        env = os.environ["ENV_PREFIX"]
        dynamodb_table_name = f"{env}-dynamodb-table"
        bucket = f"{env}-s3-bucket"
        
        # Get the current date and time to use as the key for the CSV file
        current_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")
        key = f"{current_date}-s3-bucket-key"

        # Initialize DynamoDB and S3 clients
        dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')

        try:
            # Scan the DynamoDB table to get all items
            response = dynamodb.scan(TableName=dynamodb_table_name)
            items = response['Items']

            # Define the custom headers for the CSV file
            CSV_HEADERS = ["header1", "header2"]

            # Create a temporary CSV file in memory
            csv_buffer = io.StringIO()
            csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_buffer, fieldnames=CSV_HEADERS)
            csv_writer.writeheader()

            # Write DynamoDB items to the CSV file
            for item in items:
                csv_writer.writerow({header: item.get(header, {}).get('S', '') for header in CSV_HEADERS})

            # Upload the CSV file to S3
            s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())

            return {
                'statusCode': 200,
                'body': f'Data extracted and stored in s3://{bucket}/{key}'
            }

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {str(e)}")
            return {
                'statusCode': 500,
                'body': 'Error extracting data from DynamoDB and storing in S3.'
            }

    LOG_BASE = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "../../common/config/logbase.cfg")
    dynamodb_extract_lambda = DynamoDbExtractLambda(additional_log_config=LOG_BASE)

            
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """Entrypoint for the DynamoDB Extract lambda"""
    return DynamoDBExtractLambda.main(event, context)
```

UPDATE 16/10

My current error when running the Lambda:

```
[ERROR] NameError: name 'dynamodb_extract_lambda' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/dynamodb_extract_lambda/src/lambda_handler.py", line 61, in lambda_handler
    return dynamodb_extract_lambda.main(event, context)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot answer questions that broad. Did you run the function? Does it work? If it doesn't, what error message does it give?

Comment: Where is `LambdaApplication` coming from? What does `additional_log_config` do?

Comment: Note that you're using the client-level scan operation which is a paginated operation. You will need to test for LastEvaluatedKey in each response and re-issue scan as appropriate with ExclusiveStartKey.

Comment: Your exception doesn't match your code

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing any glaring issues with your lambda.

Two things I'd consider for improvement:

1. Your lambda first reads the whole table into memory and then uploads it from memory to S3 in one big chunk. If your table is big enough, you'll have to use larger RAM limits for your lambda and pay extra.

   S3 supports uploading in chunks (with some extra effort), so you can split your work into many smaller read-write batches which would run just as efficiently, but consume less memory.

   There is a [package](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open) which facilitates implementing exactly this pattern.
2. If your table is large, reading it in full every time can become expensive and interfere with its capacity. DynamoDB supports [CDC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html#Streams.Processing) (change data capture) through streams. Depending on your use case, you could read just the changes from the stream once in a while, or even continuously, and reconcile them with the previously saved data.

   This requires more development effort (especially if you delete data from DynamoDB), but it might pay off if your table grows large.

I should also note that AWS has a service called [Glue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/), which is designed to automate exactly the kind of task you're trying to do.

Comment: The DynamoDB table doesn't have many records in there and it's not updating regularly. We're wanting to use a Lambda as it's more cost effective for what we're needing. I've updated the current that I'm getting when I invoke the Lambda.